# How to add a scrolling text of the audio file song name on a sepecific part of a video and stream it to youtube using ffmpeg

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, streaming, rtmp

I know this is s very long and specific question but it can be broken down to these points:

- How to add a text of song name on video
- How to scroll in a specific area not from the beginning of the video to the end
- How to stream a looping video and loop through multiple audio files to youtube/twitch.

I kinda got the third point but i think its not an elegant solution

`ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i back.gif -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 3000k -maxrate 3000k \ -bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 \ -ar 44100  -f flv rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/$key`

I also found this script that adds a scrolling image (input.jpg) to specific aree of a video but i coudlnt integrate it with the script above

`ffmpeg -y -ignore_loop 0 -r 25 -i back.gif -loop 1 -r 25 -i input.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=270:257:360:55[c0];[c0][1:v]overlay=y='257-t*257*0.04':eof_action=endall[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=x=360:y=55:eof_action=endall" -t 50 output.mp4`